# Xamarin CarouselView error: Error inflating class CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I'm trying to use CarouselView to create a horizontal ListView since a client of mine does not like the vertical ListView I have implemented in their project. I tried to follow several tutorials, but to no avail.

I have a hunch that the issue is with the nuget packages I downloaded or with the namespace I'm using in the xml. I am using Visual studio 2019 in a Xamarin Android App.

**Here is a list of nuget packages I downloaded for the Carousel View:**

CarouselView

CarouselView.FormsPlugin

CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Fix

Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2083

**Here is the code in my content_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    
        <forms:CarouselView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

All I added here apart from the default page you get when you create a new project is the xmlns:forms line for the namespace to use and the CarouselView tag itself.

**In my code behind OnCreate, I have this:**

```
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
    
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
```

Again, all I added here was the Init call on the CarouselViewRenderer. I am getting the error "Error inflating class CarouselView" when SetContentView is called.

Please let me know if I'm overlooking something stupid. I can't event get Intellisense to suggest CarouselView in xml, so I'm sure there's something wrong. Maybe it cant find the tag? Which is why I'm thinking it could be a namespace issue.

**What I tried:**

I tried swapping around the Init call and call it in a different order, but nothing worked.

I looked for questions similar to this in the GitHub forums but no solution seems to apply to my case.

I tried changing the tag name in xml to something like CarouselVie without the 'w' and I get the same error, which means it probably isn't finding that tag to begin with.

I tried changing the namespaces and looking for different nuget packages to download but again nothing worked.

Comment: you are using the Forms CarouselView in an Android layout file

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you can't just throw a Xamarin Forms control into an Xamarin Android page

Comment: Then what do I do? How do I get a horizontal list view? Is there a CarouselView I can use for an Android page? Tbh I'm quite confused about this whole thing

Comment: use RecyclerView, or look at the many different implementations of horizontal list views available on the net.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot. Can you just clarify why exactly Xamarin Forms controls do not work in Android Apps? I'm relatively new to Xamarin and up until now I thought Xamarin Forms was a way to create cross platform UI that translates to both native android and ios. Is it because my app is an Android app? i.e. I can use Xamarin Forms if it was a Mobile app instead of the specific Android app?

Comment: Forms is a UI library built on top of iOS/android.  It is extensively documented on the Xamarin site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From document [What is Xamarin.Forms?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms) ,we know that

> Xamarin.Forms is an open-source UI framework. Xamarin.Forms allows
> developers to build Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and Windows
> applications from a single shared codebase.
>
> Xamarin.Forms allows developers to create user interfaces in XAML with
> code-behind in C#. These interfaces are rendered as performant native
> controls on each platform.
>
> At runtime, Xamarin.Forms utilizes platform renderers to convert the
> cross-platform UI elements into native controls on Xamarin.Android,
> Xamarin.iOS and UWP. This allows developers to get the native look,
> feel and performance while realizing the benefits of code sharing
> across platforms.

So, you can use Xamarin Forms controls (`CarouselView`) in forms'app,and deploy the app to your android devices or ios devices.

From above description you posted, I think you're confused about `CarouselView`'s usage.

Since the `CarouselView` is a control of xamarin form, you should use it in xamarin forms's app rather than referencing it in Android.

For how to use `CarouselView`, you can refer to the official document : [Xamarin.Forms CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/).

And there is a sample([Xamarin.Forms - CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-carouselviewdemos/)) included in this document, you can download it and deploy it to your android device which will help you understand it better.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that that was the mistake I was making. I swapped to using RecyclerView for the intended horizontal ListView I wanted and was actually surprised by how I didn't come accross it until now. It was also very easy to use, so that solved my issue.